# How to Add a Splash Screen or Initial View to the Xcode iPhone Utility Template

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

1. I have made an application using the utility template.
2. I want to add one more view when the application launches (like a splash screen.)
3. In this view, I have three buttons. When I press one of the three buttons, the main view of the utility templete will be load.

Please help me if possible send code..thanks in advance

Comment: http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-making-a-splash-screen/ this is the good way for approching the splash screen using delegates with your own duration

Answer (score 8):

A splash screen and an initial view are two entirely separate constructs.

A splash screen is a simple image with no active UI. You create a splash screen by putting an image file named "default.png" into the resources. The app will automatically display that at startup before any views load. The Apple Human Interface Guidelines say to avoid the use of splash screens whenever possible. Their proper use is to create the illusion that the app has started more quickly than it has by presenting an image of the UI so the user can can begin to orient themselves. By the time the user reads the interface and goes to touch the screen, the real UI should be active.

You want an initial view, not a true splash screen. You don't really need to be using the utility template. That template is configured to show the simplest two view app possible anything more and you should select the navigation based project.

You can modify your existing project by adding you initial view as the rootcontroller of the navigation controller in the utilities project. The Apple documents on the navigation controller have sample code to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something kind of similar right now, the difference is I'm not using "Default.png", but an animation of images instead. The problem is I can't see to find quite the right void method to make my animation load when the application loads, not every time i return to the mainviewcontroller. However your problem has a simple answer that I have overlooked before, rather than make a splash screen before your main view loads, make your mainview into your "splash screen" and set it to link to other subviews.

```
- (IBAction)pageOne {  
    ExampleViewController *ProView =
    [[ExampleViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"ExampleViewController"
    bundle:nil];

    ExampleView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentModalViewController:ProView animated:YES];
}
```

Something along those lines, I tried to share a screenshot of all this as well but I guess I'm not reputable enough to do so.

Comment: using this helpfull to switch page tanks dude, i only supported yoou